# Help parse "There is much more to preventing employee crime than background checks..."

Tags: sentence-construction, comparative, parsing, parallelism

Consider:

> There is much more to **preventing** employee crime than background checks and traditional audits. It's not just about the employees you don't know; some of the biggest crimes are committed by long-tenured employees who have gained the corporation's trust.
>
> --*When the Cat’s Away* by Doug Karpp [Link](http://www.garp.org/risk-news-and-resources/2014/june/when-the-cat%E2%80%99s-away.aspx)

I understand the first sentence this way:

As to **preventing** employee crime, there is much more than background checks and traditional audits.

I think **preventing** is a gerund here. *Preventing employee crime* couldn't be semantically in parallel with *background checks and traditional audits*.

Is my understanding correct?

And I ran across this sentence before:

> There is much more to the universe than meets the eye on earth.

Does this have the same structure as the former one? Can you please adjust these two to a more straightforward version or template?

Comment: Yes. It's *[There is more to X than Y]*. (Y is *checks and audits* in the first example, and *(that) meets the eye* in the second.)

Comment: I knew that; I'm more interested in the form of X and Y. @DamkerngT. Obviously, these two examples don't have an one-on-one relationship.

Comment: I think of X and Y as things. X is a thing, Y is another thing (in this pattern, Y is part of X).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parse is correct.

The underlying idiom is ***[quantity Y] to X***, meaning *X consists of [quantity Y]*.

> a hundred cents to the dollar
>   two cups to a pint
>   ten millimeters to a centimeter

With measures like these you may also say *in X* (“two cups in a pint”), and when you are talking of properties of *X* you use *of* (“five stages of growth”); but when X is a target or goal, you use *to*, often with *steps* as the *Y*:

> Six Steps to Success
>   Three Steps to Better Health

(Note that this is not the same as *[quantity Y] **for** X*, which does not imply that the *Y* units are sufficient to achieve *X*, merely that each contributes to achieving *X*. And it is not the same *to* which is used with infinitives: *Three ways to improve your health*.)

You may also use indefinite quantifiers like *some Y* or *a few Y*, or comparative quantifiers like *more/fewer than [quantity] Y* or *more/fewer Y than [quantity]*.

> There are [more than two cups] to a quart.

And of course any such quantifier can also be employed as a pronoun, with the ‘unit’ *Y* understood. That’s what is going on in your sentence; indeed, the notion of units has dissolved into something uncountable like *activity*, so the verb becomes singular.

> There ***is*** [much ***more*** than background checks and traditional audits] ***to*** [preventing employee crime].

Finally, the sentence has been rearranged to put the focus on the inadequate checks and audits.

Comment: The underlying thing is always treasure. I can discern sth embedded in this comparative sentence but cannot find out. Now I see the light. Thx so much!

Answer (score 6):

> Is my understanding correct?

Yes.

> I think preventing is a gerund here.

Correct.

> *Preventing employee crime* couldn't be semantically in parallel with *background checks and traditional audits*.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by *in parallel*. They are definitely not equivalent, but they are related. *Background checks and traditional audits* are ways to accomplish (or at least attempt) the prevention of employee crime, but they are not the only ways.

> There is much more to the universe than meets the eye on earth.
>   Does this have the same structure as the former one?

Yes, more or less: *there is [much] more to [something] than [something else]*.

> Can you please adjust these two to a more straightforward version or template?

*There is more to [noun] than [things]* means that *noun* includes *things*, but also has significant or substantial other, possibly unmentioned, components or aspects. *Things* does not describe or encompass the entirety of *noun*, and often (though certainly not always or even most times) when we make this statement, *things* represents the most obvious, facile or naive portions of *noun*.

Comment: +1 I think OP's "parallelism" issue goes to the question (not so obvious to a learner as it is to us) of whether the underlying structure might be "There is more to preventing crime than [there is] to background checks".

Comment: Thanks, that's a great insight. I was rooting for some sort of parallel construction there but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I think that _"There is more to preventing crime than [there is] to background checks"_ is not the same as _"There is [much more than background checks and traditional audits] to [preventing employee crime]."_ The former doesn't suggest X is part of Y; they could be different things with different constituents, right? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Quite right