# As for / as to with people and new subjects

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

As far as I understand from my research on internet, there is no clear consensus on their usage.

> I found one speaker saying: "*When you introduce a subject related to
>   what you have just been spoken of, you can used both of them
>   interchangeablely but if you talk about something on its own, which is
>   not related to what you were just talking about, you can use only*
>   ***as to***"
>
> I found another speaker saying: "I use ***only as for*** to introduce a
>   new topic*" which contradicts with the second part of the quoted
>   opinion above.
>
> And I found lots of speakers saying: "***as for*** is used for people
>   not **as to**"

What do you think about those opinions above? + Which versions would you use in the examples below?

> 1- He's here. ***As for*** the others, they'll arrive later.
>
> 2- He's here. ***As to*** the others, they'll arrive later.
>
> 3- I wasn't hurt in the accident. ***As for*** my car, it's going to
>   be in the garage for a long time.
>
> 4- I wasn't hurt in the accident. ***As to*** my car, it's going to be
>   in the garage for a long time.
>
> 5- Hello, Newbie, and welcome to the forums. Please remember to give
>   your threads appropriate titles. ***As for*** your question,...
>
> 6- Hello, Newbie, and welcome to the forums. Please remember to give
>   your threads appropriate titles. ***As to*** your question,...

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/46228/3463

Answer (score 1):

I think the first quoted statement is incorrect. i do not think that "as for" ca only be used to introduce a topic related to the previous one, although it is often used that way.

The second statement is not an opinion at all. It merely states what the speaker does, it does not say that everyone else must or should do the same.

The third statement  "as for is used for people not as to" again i disagree with. I think "as for" may be used more often when the subject is a person, but i don't think 'as to" is forbidden in that case.

As for the example sentences in the question:

Number 1 seems perfectly natural to me. Number 2 seems somehow odd, and i don't think I would write it, but i can't say that it is wrong.

Number 3 seems perfectly natural to me. Number 4 seems slightly less natural, but I might write it. Neither seems at all wrong.

Numbers 5 and 6 both seem seem natural. I might slightly favor 5, but might well write 6.